# Buildozer built app chrashes: jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Didn't find class

Tags: python, buildozer

I used logcat to see why app crashesh, result is here:

```
02-19 15:47:11.942 21537 21624 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_export_func.pxi", line 26, in jnius.jnius.find_javaclass
02-19 15:47:11.944 21537 21624 I python  :    File "jnius/jnius_utils.pxi", line 91, in jnius.jnius.check_exception
02-19 15:47:11.945 21537 21624 I python  :  jnius.jnius.JavaException: JVM exception occurred: Didn't find class "org.renpy.android.PythonActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/me.mitja.testi-bLnHXylo6xtj-klSnNJ1dw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/me.mitja.testi-bLnHXylo6xtj-klSnNJ1dw==/lib/arm, /data/app/me.mitja.testi-bLnHXylo6xtj-klSnNJ1dw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib, /product/lib]] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
```

I don't know what even is jnius. :D.

Answer (score 0):

In your log, **jnius** refers to [Pyjnius](https://pypi.org/project/pyjnius/), a library that, in Android, is used by others such as Plyer. However, your exception *might* be caused because the **android** package is missing from your app. Try adding `android` to your Buildozer requirements list. Then clean up your build and rebuild with the new settings:

```sh
buildozer android clean
buildozer -v android debug
```